# How to change the number of rows in an iOS UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

How to change rows number in text edit programaticaly and graphicaly (in interface builder)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. A text *field* has a single row of text.

If you need multiple rows of text you should use the `UITextView` component.